# Set and get form fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

**NOTE** 
I am sorry if this is wrong place to post plugin information That I have developed. I believe this will help.

I am wondering if there any way to to set form fields automatically based on object.
I means if I have a object

```
  user = {
    text: ['text fields1', 'text fields2'],
    radio: 1,
    checkbox:false,
    select: '4'
}
```

and a form

```
 <form>
<input name='user.text.0' type='text' />
    <input name='user.text.1' type='text' />
<input name='user.radio' type='radio' value='1'/>
<input name='user.radio' type='radio' value='2'/>
<input name='user.checkbox' type='checkbox' />
<select name='user.select'>
<option value='1'> 1 </option>
<option value='2'> 2 </option>
<option value='3'> 3 </option>
<option value='4'> 4 </option>
</select>
</form>
```

Is there any JavaScript library which automatically fill all the form fields?

I also want  a method which return form  as an object.

I means if I call that method it should return

```
     {
    text: ['text fields1', 'text fields2'],
    radio: 1,
    checkbox:false,
    select: '4'
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a small [JavaScript library](https://github.com/anoopchaurasia/Form-Manager).
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rn8nW/7/)

it has two methods `FormManager.setData(Element, data)` and `FormManager.getData(Element)`.
You can set form fields using `FormManager.setData` and you can get form fields data as a object using FormManager.getData.
it uses fields name to create object keys and wise-versa.

I developed this so that I should not read form fields one by one.